# startup options "nodisplay" and "noFigureWindows" in Matlab

Tags: matlab, startup, figure

I'm new to Matlab and I just ran into an issue when running the code:

```
> In uitools\private\warnfiguredialog at 19
  In waitbar at 39
  In ExcelGUILauncher at 13
  In remoteParallelFunction at 31
Warning: This functionality is no longer supported under the -nodisplay and
-noFigureWindows startup options. For more information, see "Changes to
-nodisplay and -noFigureWindows Startup Options" in the MATLAB Release Notes.
To view the release note in your system browser, run
web('http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/rn/br5ktrh-1.html#br5ktrh-3',
'-browser')
```

The web was a dead link, could anyone suggest how can I revise?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the command `waitbar` raises a figure window to display the wait bar, which is functionality that is not supported when you're running with the `-nodisplay` or `-noFigureWindows` options.

Either rewrite your code to not use `waitbar` (perhaps it could display a series of dots at the command line instead, or a 'percent done' text instead), or run MATLAB without those options.

You should also report it as a bug to MathWorks that the documentation link is dead - they should be able to redirect it to the up-to-date link.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Matlab and could you advice where can I add the waitbar choices? Thanks!

Comment: You typically call `waitbar` using some command like `waitbar(0.3)`, indicating that you are 30% done, and causing the waitbar to move to 30% complete. I'm suggesting that instead of that, you replace the `waitbar` command with a command that does something very simple such as use `disp` to display 30 dots at the command line, and perhaps the text "30%".

Answer (score 0):

If the aim is having a silent, windowless, console start of matlab, I happily achieve it via

```
 matlab -nodesktop -nosplash
```

moreover, if a script should run, I do

```
 matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r path/to/script.
```

Comment: Is this a Linux command? I'm running it on Windows platform and I only click on the icon of Matlab to open. Where can I put these scripts in?

Comment: @Twinkle, run them from a terminal. In windows, powershell should be fine.